# Laravel 5.6 - Getting an error when I use php artisan db:seed

Tags: php, database, laravel-5.6

I'm trying to insert multiple data with help of DatabaseSeeder. But I'm getting this error. Any help is appreciated.

```html
Seeding: BorgerNotatsTableSeeder

   Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : Array to string conversion (SQL: insert into `borger_notats` (`user_id`, `borger_id`, `titel`, `beskrivelse`, `closed`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (1, 1, Autem ipsa praesentium ducimus unde., Ipsum fugiat ab culpa aut., 0, 2018-12-09 16:00:59, 2018-12-09 16:00:59))

  at /Users/sajidlatif/Code/humancare-laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:664
    660|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    661|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    662|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    663|         catch (Exception $e) {
  > 664|             throw new QueryException(
    665|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    666|             );
    667|         }
    668| 

  Exception trace:

  1   ErrorException::("Array to string conversion")
      /Users/sajidlatif/Code/humancare-laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/MySqlConnection.php:80

  2   PDOStatement::bindValue()
      /Users/sajidlatif/Code/humancare-laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/MySqlConnection.php:80

  Please use the argument -v to see more details.
```

My migrations table looks like this

```html
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('borger_notats', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('user_id');
            $table->integer('borger_id');
            $table->string('titel');
            $table->string('beskrivelse');
            $table->boolean('closed')->default(0);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

My UserFactory looks like this

```html
$factory->define(App\BorgerNotat::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'user_id' => 1,
        'borger_id' => 1,
        'titel' => $faker->sentences(10),
        'beskrivelse' => $faker->sentences(10),
        'closed' => $faker->boolean($chanceOfGettingTrue = 10)
    ];
});
```

My BorgerNotatTableSeeder looks like this

```html
class BorgerNotatsTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
   
    public function run()
    {
        factory(App\BorgerNotat::class, 7)->create();
    }
}
```

And my DatabaseSeeder looks like this

```html
class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    public function run()
    {
        // $this->call(UsersTableSeeder::class);
        $this->call(BorgerNotatsTableSeeder::class);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked your seeding values? It seems you are trying to pass an array as a string. I can't really see where, but I would get the types you are passing in your `UserFactory`

Comment: I have inserted the UserFactory snippet. See above please

Comment: This is the values: (SQL: insert into `borger_notats` (`user_id`, `borger_id`, `titel`, `beskrivelse`, `closed`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (1, 1, Autem ipsa praesentium ducimus unde., Ipsum fugiat ab culpa aut., 0, 2018-12-09 16:00:59, 2018-12-09 16:00:59))

Comment: I have seen the SQL... But during the beginning of your migration to the error, there is an array which is being passed instead of a string. The SQL doesn't make it obvious where the problem is; that's why I asked for the types of your `UserFactory` types. Those may be where you are getting the error.

Comment: Thanks for your help. You were the reason why I found the issue :)

Comment: No problem, man... Those error messages can be quite cryptic, hard to narrow it down sometimes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the issue. 
It looks like that the UserFactory for the "sentences" has an array, so I had to use "sentence". So I've removed the $faker->sentences(10) and replaced it with $faker->sentence(10) and it worked.

```html
$factory->define(App\BorgerNotat::class, function (Faker $faker) {
return [
    'user_id' => 1,
    'borger_id' => 1,
    'titel' => $faker->sentence(10),
    'beskrivelse' => $faker->sentence(10),
    'closed' => $faker->boolean($chanceOfGettingTrue = 10)
];
});
```